# reportProgress in angular returns the total uploaded file and not the progress

Tags: angular, http, observable, angular6, angular-httpclient

in my component i have this

```
this.authService.addPost(post).subscribe(data => {
        if (data.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {

        console.log(data);
        } else if (data.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          if (data.body.success) {
            alert('post added');
            this.modalRef.close('Save click');
          } else {
            alert('an error has occured');
          }
        }

      });
```

and here is my service

```
addPost(post) {

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      // add authorisation
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.authToken}`
    });

    return this.httpClient.post<Addpost>('' + this.domain + 'add/addPost', post,
      {
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events',
        headers: headers,
      });
  }
```

so my problem is in the console i get the total uploaded file status and not the progress. i get something like this

```
{type: 1, loaded: 21076, total: 21076}
```

i have tried so many parameters and all to no avail

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, I haven't .

Comment: Hey guys did you see the docs about this https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events

Comment: Hey, i know it's late but have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

In this case last return full http request. You need to change target responce from data => data.body.

Profit

Comment: Instead of writing in words how to modify the code, it would be preferable to post the edited code...