# Angular: reportProgress does not return data progressively

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display the progress bar of uploading images on my website.

But I'm not getting the "loaded" value progressively in the HttpEvent response, so I'm not able to show the progress bar on the website progressively.

I'm getting the "loaded" & "total" values as equal in my 1st event response, so then how can I use it for progressing UI. See my response in the screenshot. [ScreenShot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBc88.png)

**My code is**

```
this.http.post<any>('http://localhost/api/user-photo/add', uploadData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events'
    } ).subscribe(data => {console.log(data);});
```

See this screenshot, this is what I'm getting the response.

**Response in console window:**
[ScreenShot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBc88.png)

I followed some youtube videos, they are getting the response of "loaded" value constantly increasing and I could see that they are getting multiple returns in the console window, but I'm getting only one, and the "loaded" & "total" values are same, so If I couldn't calculate the progress value.
This is the screenshot of their response, and it's working properly, I need it like this.
[ScreenShot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6rE3.png)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkvqLNcJz3Y&t=598s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKvDmzcEros&ab_channel=ThomasOliver

Could you give me any suggestion to get the "loaded" value progressively?

**I asked the same in GitHub, a person replied as the upload might be done quickly.**

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/42073

No, the upload takes time but before that, I'm getting the "loaded" value as completed.
I'm sure,  because after I got the EVENT response(see below), had to wait to get the BODY response for more than 25seconds, so I'm sure, the image was not uploaded when I got the 1st Event response.
[ScreenShot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1aK3.png)

```
{type: 1, loaded: 2292777, total: 2292777}
```

**Someone already asked this 2years ago, but no response still.**

[reportProgress in angular returns the total uploaded file and not the progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51686410/reportprogress-in-angular-returns-the-total-uploaded-file-and-not-the-progress)

Thanks & Regards

Thirumani

Comment: This will help you checkout [here](https://bezkoder.com/angular-10-file-upload/)

Answer (score 1):

**`I GOT A SOLUTION`**

Actually, I was not aware of my network speed. That quick response comes due to that reason only. I tried to upload with slower networks I could get the reportProgress constantly increasing.
This link helped me to sorted out.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/42073#issuecomment-840482014

Thank you,

Thirumani.

Answer (score 0):

That probably your server that took time to handle request, not the request transfer.

You got a `type` properties on the event, it corresponds to an HttpEventType https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpEventType

The `1` say you are sending data to server. The `3` you get later say that you begin to download the response.

Your angular application has no way to know how many time it took to the server to handle a request, it only knows how many bits were sent / recieved.

If you look on a network analyser (next to navigator console in most browser ) there are some value you could be interested in:

- `Request send` That's what you calculate with your code (the `type: 1` things)
- `TTFB` The time it took to the server to handle your request (your browser doesn't know what operation server do on received data ) and send you the first byte of response
- `Content download` the time it took to download server response

Example with chrome, other browser offer same fonctionality [image: Example with chrome]

Comment: Hi, Romain Vidal, Thanks for your quick reply, I'll check your suggestion.